# Seeking Advice on Tracking Membership Changes Over Time in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

Hi StackExchange SQLers!

I’m working on a report to track changes in our non-profit’s membership over time. The audit table only logs changes, not end-of-month values for all accounts. I need to count the account_id for all year-months, including those year-months where there is no audit record but the membership existed, based on their last value prior to the end of the year-month. i.e. if a membership changed in January 2023 and then again in March 2023, I need to count the February 2023 membership for the account_id even though no explicit record exists.

- **Objective:** Reporting membership composition changes over time for a non-profit organization based on an audit table.

**Challenge:** The audit table only logs changes to account membership values, not end-of-month values. We need to count account IDs for months where there are no explicit audit records but the membership exists.

---

### Example Data

#### Example of Membership Audit Table

**Note: example includes only a single account (123456) for simplicity sake; there are many thousands of accounts in the actual table*

---

| last_change_date | account_id | membership_level | membership_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/26/2023 01:38:30 | 123456 | annual_member | active |
| 02/25/2023 11:35:45 | 123456 | recurring_member | active |
| 04/26/2023 01:52:34 | 123456 | recurring_member | lapsed |
| 05/26/2023 01:52:34 | 123456 | recurring_member | active |
| 05/30/2023 08:58:19 | 123456 | major_donor | active |
| 06/20/2023 01:36:45 | 123456 | major_donor | lapsed |

The donor should be counted as annual_member/active for January, recurring/active for February and March; recurring/lapsed for April; major_donor/active for May; and major_donor/lapsed for June. I need the final record in a month if the account changed level/status multiple times.

Here’s an example of the final report output:

#### Example Report Output

*Note that I've pivoted the output for more concise display; I'm not concerned with how to pivot in SQL; rather how to effectually count records based on intermitent audit changes to memberships over year-month reporting periods).*

---

| year-month | recurring/active | recurring/lapsed | annual/active | annual/lapsed | major_donor/active | major_donor/lapsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-02 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-03 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-04 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-05 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-06 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I’m unsure whether to use a SQL script to build this output incrementally or use subqueries and window functions. Any advice would be appreciated.I'm looking primarily for approach guidance (any actual SQL demo would help, but mostly looking for your conceptual approach).

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Generate a calendar; then
2. Use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` to join it to your table for each `account_id` and then use analytic functions to find the last values for each month if there is no data for that month and number the rows within the month (in descending order); then
3. Filter to only include the rows numbered first (i.e. the last row for the month); and then
4. `PIVOT` and aggregate.

Like this:

```sql
WITH calendar (year_month) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2023-01-01', LEVEL - 1)
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6
),
month_data (year_month, account_id, membership_level, membership_status, rn) AS (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(c.year_month, 'YYYY-MM'),
         account_id,
         LAST_VALUE(membership_level) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
           PARTITION BY t.account_id
           ORDER BY c.year_month, t.last_change_date
         ),
         LAST_VALUE(membership_status) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
           PARTITION BY t.account_id
           ORDER BY c.year_month, t.last_change_date
         ),
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY t.account_id, c.year_month
           ORDER BY t.last_change_date DESC
         )
  FROM   calendar c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
         PARTITION BY (t.account_id)
         ON     c.year_month <= t.last_change_date
            AND t.last_change_date < ADD_MONTHS(c.year_month, 1)
),
last_of_month_data (year_month, account_id, membership_level, membership_status) AS (
  SELECT year_month, account_id, membership_level, membership_status
  FROM   month_data
  WHERE  rn = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM   last_of_month_data
PIVOT (
  COUNT(DISTINCT account_ID)
  FOR (membership_level, membership_status) IN (
    ('annual_member',    'active') AS annual_active,
    ('annual_member',    'lapsed') AS annual_lapsed,
    ('recurring_member', 'active') AS recurring_active,
    ('recurring_member', 'lapsed') AS recurring_lapsed,
    ('major_donor',      'active') AS donor_active,
    ('major_donor',      'lapsed') AS donor_lapsed
  )
)
ORDER BY year_month
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (last_change_date, account_id, membership_level, membership_status) AS
SELECT DATE '2023-01-26' + INTERVAL '01:38:30' HOUR TO SECOND, 123456, 'annual_member',    'active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-02-25' + INTERVAL '11:35:45' HOUR TO SECOND, 123456, 'recurring_member', 'active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-04-26' + INTERVAL '01:52:34' HOUR TO SECOND, 123456, 'recurring_member', 'lapsed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-05-26' + INTERVAL '01:52:34' HOUR TO SECOND, 123456, 'recurring_member', 'active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-05-30' + INTERVAL '08:58:19' HOUR TO SECOND, 123456, 'major_donor',      'active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-06-20' + INTERVAL '01:36:45' HOUR TO SECOND, 123456, 'major_donor',      'lapsed' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| YEAR_MONTH | ANNUAL_ACTIVE | ANNUAL_LAPSED | RECURRING_ACTIVE | RECURRING_LAPSED | DONOR_ACTIVE | DONOR_LAPSED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-02 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-03 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-04 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-05 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-06 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AE8fynaM)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to generate months calendar, get last row of month per account, join those two and use conditional aggregation:

```sql
WITH    -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (LAST_CHG_DATE, ACC_ID, MMB_LEVEL, MMB_STATUS) As
        ( Select To_Date('2023-01-26 01:38:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 123456, 'annual_member',    'active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          Select To_Date('2023-02-25 11:35:45', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 123456, 'recurring_member', 'active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          Select To_Date('2023-04-26 01:52:34', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 123456, 'recurring_member', 'lapsed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          Select To_Date('2023-05-26 01:52:34', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 123456, 'recurring_member', 'active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          Select To_Date('2023-05-30 08:58:19', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 123456, 'major_donor',      'active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          Select To_Date('2023-06-20 01:36:45', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 123456, 'major_donor',      'lapsed' FROM DUAL
        )
```

```sql
-- M a i n    S Q L :
Select  d.YR_MTH, 
        Count(Distinct Case When t.MMB_LEVEL = 'recurring_member' And t.MMB_STATUS = 'active' Then t.ACC_ID End) "RECURING_ACTIVE",
        Count(Distinct Case When t.MMB_LEVEL = 'recurring_member' And t.MMB_STATUS = 'lapsed' Then t.ACC_ID End) "RECURING_LAPSED",
        Count(Distinct Case When t.MMB_LEVEL = 'annual_member' And t.MMB_STATUS = 'active' Then t.ACC_ID End) "ANUAL_ACTIVE",
        Count(Distinct Case When t.MMB_LEVEL = 'annual_member' And t.MMB_STATUS = 'lapsed' Then t.ACC_ID End) "ANUAL_LAPSED",
        Count(Distinct Case When t.MMB_LEVEL = 'major_donor' And t.MMB_STATUS = 'active' Then t.ACC_ID End) "MAJOR_DONOR_ACTIVE",
        Count(Distinct Case When t.MMB_LEVEL = 'major_donor'  And t.MMB_STATUS = 'lapsed' Then t.ACC_ID End) "MAJOR_DONOR_LAPSED"
        -- month calendar using model clause iteration - you can do it any other way
From   (  Select  YR_MTH 
          From    ( Select 0 "YR", 0 "MTH", '0000-00' "YR_MTH" From Dual ) 
          Where   YR > 0
              MODEL  Dimension By(YR, MTH)
                     Measures (YR_MTH)
              RULES ITERATE (6)  
                  ( YR_MTH[2023, ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = CV(YR) || '-' || LPad(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1, 2, '0') )
        ) d
        -- getting last row per month
Left Join ( SELECT * FROM ( Select LAST_CHG_DATE, Max(LAST_CHG_DATE) Over(Partition By ACC_ID, To_Char(LAST_CHG_DATE, 'yyyy-mm')) "MAX_LAST_CHG_DATE", 
                                   ACC_ID, MMB_LEVEL, MMB_STATUS
                            From tbl 
                          ) 
          ) t ON(To_Char(MAX_LAST_CHG_DATE, 'yyyy-mm') = YR_MTH And t.MAX_LAST_CHG_DATE = t.LAST_CHG_DATE)
Group By  d.YR_MTH, t.MMB_LEVEL, t.MMB_STATUS
Order By  d.YR_MTH
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
YR_MTH  RECURING_ACTIVE RECURING_LAPSED ANUAL_ACTIVE ANUAL_LAPSED MAJOR_DONOR_ACTIVE MAJOR_DONOR_LAPSED
------- --------------- --------------- ------------ ------------ ------------------ ------------------
2023-01               0               0            1            0                  0                  0
2023-02               1               0            0            0                  0                  0
2023-03               0               0            0            0                  0                  0
2023-04               0               1            0            0                  0                  0
2023-05               0               0            0            0                  1                  0
2023-06               0               0            0            0                  0                  1  */
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a set for a second account id to illustrate the behaviour - just by doubling your input for a second account_id:

```
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(last_change_date,account_id,membership_level,membership_status) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '01/26/2023 01:38:30',123456,'annual_member'   ,'active' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '02/25/2023 11:35:45',123456,'recurring_member','active' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '04/26/2023 01:52:34',123456,'recurring_member','lapsed' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '05/26/2023 01:52:34',123456,'recurring_member','active' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '05/30/2023 08:58:19',123456,'major_donor'     ,'active' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '06/20/2023 01:36:45',123456,'major_donor'     ,'lapsed' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '01/26/2023 01:38:30',123457,'annual_member'   ,'active' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '02/25/2023 11:35:45',123457,'recurring_member','active' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '04/26/2023 01:52:34',123457,'recurring_member','lapsed' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '05/26/2023 01:52:34',123457,'recurring_member','active' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '05/30/2023 08:58:19',123457,'major_donor'     ,'active' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '06/20/2023 01:36:45',123457,'major_donor'     ,'lapsed' FROM dual
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
-- need a series of month end dates - modify as needed
month_ends(mthend) AS (
            SELECT DATE '2023-01-31' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-02-28' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-03-31' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-04-30' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-05-31' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-06-30' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-07-31' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-08-31' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-09-30' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-10-31' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-11-30' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-12-31' FROM dual
)
,
vertical AS (
  SELECT
    mthend,i.*
  , LAST_VALUE(membership_level||'/'||membership_status IGNORE NULLS) 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY last_change_date) AS memb_status
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY last_change_date) AS rn
  FROM indata i
  JOIN month_ends ON TO_CHAR(last_change_date,'YYYY-MM') = TO_CHAR(mthend,'YYYY-MM')
)
SELECT
  mthend
, SUM(CASE memb_status WHEN 'major_donor/active'      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "major_donor/active"
, SUM(CASE memb_status WHEN 'major_donor/lapsed'      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "major_donor/lapsed"
, SUM(CASE memb_status WHEN 'annual_member/active'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "annual_member/active"
, SUM(CASE memb_status WHEN 'recurring_member/active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "recurring_member/active"
, SUM(CASE memb_status WHEN 'recurring_member/lapsed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "recurring_member/lapsed"
FROM vertical
GROUP BY mthend
ORDER BY mthend
-- out    mthend   | major_donor/active | major_donor/lapsed | annual_member/active | recurring_member/active | recurring_member/lapsed 
-- out ------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------
-- out  2023-01-31 |                  0 |                  0 |                    2 |                       0 |                       0
-- out  2023-02-28 |                  0 |                  0 |                    0 |                       2 |                       0
-- out  2023-04-30 |                  0 |                  0 |                    0 |                       0 |                       2
-- out  2023-05-31 |                  2 |                  0 |                    0 |                       2 |                       0
-- out  2023-06-30 |                  0 |                  2 |                    0 |                       0 |                       0
```